# How to use another key in my translation string

Tags: laravel, localization

In my localized laravel app I want to use a translation key within another string.

Something like this:

```
'appname' => "My app",
'reset.subject' => "Reset password for _('appname')"
```

So the result of `@lang("app.reset.subject")` would be `Reset password for My app`.

Any ideas if that's possible and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the string like any other php string.

```
'reset.subject' => "Reset password for " . _('appname')
```

Comment: This sounds good but didn't work for me. I get `"Reset password for appname"`. No matter if I use `_('appname')` or `_('app.appname')`. The _ method seems to be found as there is no error and an actual output but no translation. Do I need to include anything in the language file like `use ClassXY` for this?

Comment: You have to use the file name where the string is in front of translation strings, so you have to use `_('{filename}.appname')`. Or are you trying to get the value from config?

Comment: I use `'reset.subject' => "Reset password for " . _('app.appname')` as the name of the file is "app.php". Using `config("app.name")` instead of `_('appname')` works when I defined a value in the config file. This is a good start for the app name but I would be happy to use translation keys within my translations. Does it work for you? What am I missing?